# Add value of option tag to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys I have the following code, working demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qf28f9fd/21/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    console.log('selected', selected);
    $("#writer").append(selected);
  });
})
```

```html
<p class="Title">
  <h2 id="writer">MARIO PUZO'S</h2>
  <h1 id="godfathertitle">THE GODFATHER</h1>
  <h1 id="shawshanktitle" style="display: none;">Shawshank Redemption</h1>
  <h1 id="fightclubtitle" style="display: none;">Fight Club</h1>

  <h4>by Mario Puzo and Francis Ford Coppola</h4> TRANSCRIPT

</p>
<div id="image">

</div>
<div class="Txt2">


  ADE FROM BLACK: Int. of Don Corleone's home office -day
  <br>
  <br> BONASERA
  <font style="font-style:italic" ;>(seated in front of the Dons
    <select id="one">
    <option value="Paolo Peters">desk</option>
    <option value="Shirin Grand">dark, empty room(shawshank redemption)</option>
    <option value ="Jeroen Pronk">SOCIAL ROOM(fight club)</option>
    </select>, facing the camera)</font>
  <br>



  <div id="partshawshank2" style="display:none">shawshank</div>
  <div id="partfightclub2" style="display:none">shawshank</div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <br>
```

I am adding the text from an option select to a div. 
But instead of adding the **text** I want to add the **value**, can anybody help me with this? I am struggling with getting the value. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just replace `text()` with `val()` ?

Comment: Or even easier, `$('#one').change(function() {
    $("#writer").append(this.value);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem. Just change following code:

```
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

to:

```
var selected = document.getElementById("one").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

To

```
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qf28f9fd/22/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script with the below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#one').val();

    $("#writer").append(selected);

  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#one').change(function() {
   var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
   console.log('selected', selected);
   $("#writer").html("").append(selected);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();`
The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.
Refer [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Also use  `<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Room</option>`

as your default select option, because in your case when the first option (dark) is selected, no result is obtained.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var titles = ["THE GODFATHER", "Shawshank Redemption", "Fight Club"];
  $('#one').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $("#title").html(titles[id]);
    $("#writer").html(selected);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="Title">
  <h2 id="writer">MARIO PUZO'S</h2>
  <h1 id="title">THE GODFATHER</h1>
  <h4>by Mario Puzo and Francis Ford Coppola</h4> TRANSCRIPT
</p>
<div id="image">
</div>
<div class="Txt2">
  ADE FROM BLACK: Int. of Don Corleone's home office -day
  <br>
  <br> BONASERA
  <font style="font-style:italic" ;>(seated in front of the Dons
    <select id="one">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Room</option>    
<option id=0 value="Paolo Peters">desk</option>
<option id= 1 value="Shirin Grand">dark, empty room(shawshank redemption)</option>
<option id =2 value ="Jeroen Pronk">SOCIAL ROOM(fight club)</option>
</select>, facing the camera)</font>
  <br>



  <div id="partshawshank2" style="display:none">shawshank</div>
  <div id="partfightclub2" style="display:none">shawshank</div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
```